# SmartyStreets jQuery element positioning breaks

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, smartystreets

My address form is located below a twitter bootstrap tab set. These tabs have varying heights. As the user switches between tabs, the SmartyStreets "smarty-ui" element does not update it's absolute positioning. Instead, the form may now appear higher or lower on the page and the checkbox stays where it was originally positioned. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What happens if you call $(window).resize() when a tab is changed?

Comment: Bingo! I added $(window).resize() to my tab click event and now the SmartyStreets verify button updates to the field position. Thanks!