# SmartyStreets AngularJS smarty-ui position not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smartystreets

I am using SmartyStreets' LiveAddress in an angularJS application to do address validation and autofill on 2 fields in a form. When the user clicks submit, a div is created above the form with either a success or failure message. This div pushes the form down, but the `smarty-ui` divs do not move, so the `smarty-tag-check` divs are no longer lined up properly with their associated fields.

I tried adding `angular.element($window).resize();` to my code after the success div is displayed (based on the comment in [SmartyStreets jQuery element positioning breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068460/smartystreets-jquery-element-positioning-breaks)), but am not seeing any effect. Is this an improper way to force a window resize in AngularJS, or alternatively is there a better way to keep the `smarty-ui` divs in the proper location?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a small example of your situation in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Did you try calling resize on the div instead of on the window? I had to call jQuery('#bodyDIV').resize(); instead of resizing the window in one instance to get my verify button in the right position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue with just calling a resize with `angular.element($window).resize();` was that it was performing the resize before angular had finished building the new page. I've gotten around this by adding it via a timeout instead: 

`$timeout(function(){angular.element($window).resize()}, 500);`